# Create an array from an array and keep the same order

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I've created a very simple deck of cards. I'm using 3 arrays, $deck, $cards, & $used. $deck is the cards in play, $cards is a comparison array, and $used is a discard array. When cards are used from $deck they get place in the $used array. My issue is when they are placed in the $used array they are put into numeric order. I don't want this. I need them to be in the same order that they are removed from the $deck array. The full code is below.

```
<?php

/*
    This code creates a deck of cards and deals them
    It also creates a discard pile of used cards. It never
    deals duplicates and will re-shuffle the deck if it
    gets under 7 cards.
*/

dealCards();

/* 
    This function creates the deck of cards.
    It will deal out 5 cards and remove those
    5 cards from the deck.
*/

function dealCards() {

    // checks to see if a session has been created
    if (isset($_SESSION["deck"])) {
        $deck = $_SESSION["deck"];
    } else {    
    // if session has not been created it
        $deck = range(1, 52);
        shuffle($deck);
        $_SESSION["deck"] = $deck;
    }

    // comparison array. 
    $cards = range(1, 52);

// will use the same deck until it has 7 or less cards
if (count($deck) > 7) {

// deals 5 cards from the array $deck
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {

        print "<img src="/main/deck/$deck[$i].png" alt="Card: $deck[$i]" />";

        // removes dealt cards from the deck
        unset($deck[$i]);
        // clears empty values from the array
        $deck = array_values(array_filter($deck));
        // replaces session data with new deck
        $_SESSION["deck"] = $deck;
    }

} else {

    // shuffle the full 52 cards again if the deck is less than 7 cards
    $deck = range(1, 52);
    shuffle($deck);
    $_SESSION["deck"] = $deck;

}
    /*
        compares $deck to the comparison array $cards
        and places the differences in an array 
        called $used which then can be used as a discard
        pile.
    */
    $used = array_diff($cards, $deck);

    // testing purposes.
    print "<pre>";
    print_r ($deck);
    print "</pre>";

    print "<pre>";
    print_r ($used);
    print "</pre>";

}

?>
```

Comment: If you need to have them in the same order, store the array in the session as well. At the moment before `unset($deck[$i]);`, do a `$_SESSION['used'][] = $deck[$i];`. Without some place to store the order in which cards have been used, you can never 'rebuild' that exact array in the same order.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and they still fill the $used array in numeric order.

Comment: then [you're doing something wrong](https://eval.in/233094), or perhaps you are doing other stuff with it that results in a reorder. Out of the box, it just works as illustrated in the linked code.

Comment: I got it working, however it saves only 5 cards in the $used array. every deal it replaces the previous 5 with the new 5 cards that were dealt. I'm trying to keep every card played in $used until the deck is re-shuffled.

Comment: The you're overwriting `$_SESSION['used']` somewhere. There can be 2 main reasons for this: (1) a logical error which indeed resets `$_SESSION['used']` somewhere (2) you might have [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) enabled (which has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.) and you're using a `$used` variable somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes in my mind is that when you unset your `deck` array

```
    // removes dealt cards from the deck
    unset($deck[$i]);
```

you can put the card in the `$used` array

```
    // removes dealt cards from the deck then put them in the discard pile
    $used[$i] = $deck[$i];
```

But this would work only for the first time. In a second usage of `dealCards` it would be overwritten. 
Plus, the `$used` array will surely have some empty position in it.
Do you need them to be stored permanently?

Comment: I just need them removed and stored until the $deck array has 7 or less values, at that point the entire function resets.

Comment: Let me get this straight, if you had this kind of progression `1, 4, 6, 9` of discarded cards, how should the `$used` array look like?

Comment: Say the first 5 cards are 9 5 2 7 6 and the second set of 5 are 10 8 4 3 1. when the $used array is generated it drops in order like 1 2 3 4 5. They should be stored in the same order they are dealt. from the 2 hand examples the $used array should look like 9 5 2 7 6 10 8 4 3 1

Comment: So why don't you just use `array_push($used, $deck[$i])` ?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working. The code needs cleaned up a bit but at least it works. Thanks for the help Wrikken and everyone else. Below is the modified working code.

```
<?php

/*
    This code creates a deck of cards and deals them
    It also creates a discard pile of used cards. It never
    deals duplicates and will re-shuffle the deck if it
    gets under 7 cards.
*/

dealCards();

/* 
    This function creates the deck of cards.
    It will deal out 5 cards and remove those
    5 cards from the deck.
*/

function dealCards() {

    $used = array();

    // checks to see if a session has been created
    if (isset($_SESSION["deck"])) {
        $deck = $_SESSION["deck"];
    } else {
        $deck = range(1, 52);
        shuffle($deck);
        $_SESSION["deck"] = $deck;
    }

// will use the same deck until it has 7 or less cards
if (count($deck) > 7) {
    if (isset($_SESSION["used"])) {
        $used = $_SESSION["used"];
    } else {    
        $_SESSION["used"] = $used;  
    }
// deals 5 cards from the array $deck

    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {

        print <img src="/main/deck/$deck[$i].png" alt="Card: $deck[$i]" />;

        $used[] = $deck[$i];
        unset($deck[$i]);
        // clears empty values from the array
        $deck = array_values(array_filter($deck));
        // replaces session data with new deck
        $_SESSION["deck"] = $deck;
    }

} else {

    // shuffle the full 52 cards again if the deck is less than 7 cards
    $deck = range(1, 52);
    shuffle($deck);
    $_SESSION["deck"] = $deck;
}

    $_SESSION["used"] = $used;

}

?>
```